# Xcode NSString in textfield

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstring

I'm completely new to Xcode and Objective-C but I have succeeded in creating a btton and when the user clicks this button a number is displayed in a textfield, but I can't seem to find a way to put text in there.

```
-(IBAction) button1pressed: (id) sender {
[field1 setIntValue:36];
}
```

Comment: How did you create the textifield? Via code or InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: interfacebuilder but have added an outlet and an Action for the button, its all working fine with the Int Value so basically I need something instead of setIntValue: 36 to setvalue to text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) button1pressed: (id) sender {
    [field1 setStringValue:@"some text"];
}
```

Method inherited from `NSControl`, Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setStringValue:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your properly making connections in xCode between the IB Text field (I assume your using IB since you're using IBAction) and the `IBOutlet NSTextField *field1;` instance variable.